# 2 or more same name in php called in different function in js

Tags: javascript, forms

i have 2 form in same page, n that 2 form have same name.
for ex :

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <label for="supplier">Email</label>
                  <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                  <small id="pelem-error">Masukkan email supplier</small>
                </div>
```

and

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <label for="customer">Email</label>
                  <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                  <small id="pelem-error">Masukkan email customer</small>
                </div>
```

this 2 input both has same name "email"
but i want to call it in different function since it for different table
js :

```
$("#form_supplier").on("submit",function(){
var email_supplier = $("#email").val();
```

and

```
$("#form_customer").on("submit",function(){
var email_customer= $("#email").val();
```

but the email from customer is called in supplier form.. is there a way to call it the email of form customer in js? pls help, thx!

Comment: you can't have same id's for multiple elements in a single page.

Comment: there is no other way? because i use many modals in 1 page.. n each form in the different modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all html element id's must be unique for proper expected behavior to occur (otherwise it will take the first id it finds in the DOM, sometimes the last, depending on reasons).

If you are unable to make your element `id` unique, then you can reference them like the following:

```
$("#form_supplier").on("submit",function(){
    var email_supplier = $("#form_supplier input[name='email']").val();
});
$("#form_customer").on("submit",function(){
    var email_customer = $("#form_customer input[name='email']").val();
});
```

Another way is thusly (using the form as the scope):

```
$("#form_supplier").on("submit",function(){
    var email_supplier = $("input[name='email']",$(this)).val();
});
$("#form_customer").on("submit",function(){
    var email_customer = $("input[name='email']",$(this)).val();
});
```

But you still need to remove all the duplicate `id` values, so your DOM is clean.

Comment: how about the small text for warning?
can i use like
$("#form_supplier small['pelem-error']")
and
$("#form_pelanggan small['pelem-error']") ?

Comment: Yes. This is how jquery selectors work. You have a very wide range of ways you can reference like-named items that are located under un-like-named items.

Comment: More about jquery selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/